# DB2 via OLEDB in VB

Tags: vb.net, db2, visual-studio-2019, oledb, .net-4.7.2

I've researched google and stackoverflow, but we are drawing blanks....we have a team using the same code to use IBMDADB2 driver with an olebconnection to connect to the companies DB2 database.  Half the team can connect fine, other half gets an error.  This is visual studio 2019, VB, framework 4.7.2

Basics of error is System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x8004d01c): CLI0106E  Connection is closed.  SQLSTATe=08003 CLI0119E Unexpected System failure.  SQLSTATE=58004.

This occurs when trying to open the connection.

The machines where this fails on, can connect fine to the database using IBMS tool.

We've compared db2cli.ini and db2dsdriver.cfg files....They all seem to be the same.

Have also used db2md -i -w db2clpsetcp

It's just using OleDbConnection in framework 4.72
Product Version on System.Data is 4.7.3062.0

DB2Level output

DB21085I This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "DB2") uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11055" with level identifier "0606010F". Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.5.5010.1723", "s2103171200", "DYN2103171200WIN64", and Fix Pack "1". Product is installed at "C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB" with DB2 Copy Name "DB2COPY1".

This is what i have, and it works on my machine
IBM Data Server Client - DB2COPY   version 11.5.5010.1723

Teammate has
IBM Data Server Runtime Client DB2COPY1 version 11.1.1011.1315
and doesnt work on her machine

**Added 08/22/2022 -  Teammate updated driver...matches mine, same error.

Comment: Have you re-installed the driver? is that automated/scripted (or manual choices made).  You can debug this with the windows sysinternal procmon.

Comment: Unless you are referring to the .net System.Data.Aseclient dll , the folks that get this error are able to connect with other tools like dbeaver and ibms tool

Comment: dbeaver uses jdbc, this is different product (no shared code or files) from odbc.   Please edit your question to show the exact filename, (full product name) that gets installed for the Db2 driver. Precision matters here, as more than one package can deliver IBMDADB2, so we need to know which one is in use.

Comment: Added to original...but this is what i added  It's just using OleDbConnection in framework 4.72 Product Version on System.Data is 4.7.3062.0

Comment: I am not allowed to run the installation manager on my machine, however i can see the installed.xml file...but not sure what i am looking for in there.

Comment: i can include the output from the db2level command if that has any value

Comment: Yes `db2level` plain text output will help (not as a graphic image), and see if you can see the IBM Data Server client product name in `appwiz.cpl` (may be absent).

Comment: DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "DB2") 

uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11055" with level identifier 

"0606010F".

Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.5.5010.1723", "s2103171200", 

"DYN2103171200WIN64", and Fix Pack "1".

Product is installed at "C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB" with DB2 Copy Name "DB2COPY1".

**I have 16 appwiz.cp files on my computer....i could check the ones in my paths

Comment: Could it be a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue? Try asserting a target CPU rather than "AnyCPU" in your compile options

Comment: @SSS Tried this, no differences...Thanks though.

Comment: @JeffreyKinzer As one working machine has a newer `db2level` than one failing machine, that is an obvious thing to fix first. Check the db2level on all of the failing machines, and all of the working machines, and determine if there is a pattern. If all the failing machines have a downlevel db2level, and all of the working machines have a newer db2level, the the solution should be clear to you.